# Pages that Magento 2 frontend comprises of

Tags: magento2, frontend, cms-pages

I am trying to understand **Magento** frontend. I stuck at a question that the types of pages are available for frontend. I mean to say like pages -product grid page, checkout page. I want to know all the available pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento 2 is a complete e-commerce solution. If you want to know basic pages of magento2, here the list.

- Home Page
- Category page
- Product Page
- Cart Pages
- Product Review Page
- Checkout page
- Checkout Success/Order success page
- Customer/Account Dashboard
- Customer/Account User information page edit.
- Customer/Account Address listing page
- Customer/Account address edit page
- Customer Order listing page
- Customer order details page
- Cms Pages
- Contacts Us page